# How to send POST request with Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, api, invoke-webrequest

I tried with below option but it does not work. Can anyone help?

```
$url='some web page url'
$token='0000000000000'
$headers = @{ 'ContentType' = 'Application/Json'}
$body = @{ "userName"="username"}
Invoke-WebRequest -Method 'post' -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body ($body|ConvertTo- 
Json) -Credentials mycredentials
```

Comment: what's the question? think how to use the method POST is clear to you as you have it already specified...

Comment: Hi Toni. It throws error "code": "Unauthorized", "cause": "NA", "diagnostics": {"id":......}

Comment: hehe - how do want to authenticate, with a token or username/password? btw. is this a rest API?

Comment: its rest api, and authentication method is bearer token

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with a REST API you should use the cmdlet `invoke-restmethod`. To authenticate using a bearer token you need to build a authorization header and the parameter `-credential` is not needed, e.g.:

```
$token = [tokenString]

$header = @{
     Authorization="Bearer $token"
}

$body = @{username='username'} | convertto-json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -uri $url -Headers $header -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: getting error "Invalid Content-Type" with your example.

Comment: at least the authentication did now work, you are one step further. idk what the problem now is as I do not know with which API you try to interact?!